# Visual Studio 2010 does not discover new unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I am writing some unit tests in Visual Studio 2010. I can run all tests by using "Run all Tests in Current Context".

However, if I write a new unit test, it does not get picked up by the environment - in other words, I am not able to find it in Test List Editor, by running all tests, or anywhere else. If I unload the project and then reload it; the new test is available to run.

When I am adding a unit test, I simply add a new method to an already existing TestClass and decorating it with  [TestMethod] attribute - nothing fancy.

What might be causing this behaviour, and how do I make it work ?

Comment: What are the steps you are doing that is causing a problem? There are several ways to run tests, so it is hard to come up with a good answer.

Comment: @James, I use either "Run tests in current context" or "Run all tests in solution" from the toolbar. Normal behavior of these is to include any new tests that I have added.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. In Options under Test Tools -> Test Project, there is an option "Disable background discovery of test methods". It was turned on - I do not know how that happened, but removing the checkmark and restarting Visual Studio solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This is has been so frustrating since upgrading. Why in the world is discovery disabled by default?

Comment: Question is, how come this check box suddently checked itself on?

Comment: Awesome! This setting changed as I redid my solutions leaving the test project out of some build configurations. Could that be the cause for anyone else?

Comment: I am sure this is late, but it is because of ReSharper. I had the same issue and your screenshot shows that you have ReSharper installed just like I do.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem as well when building in debug mode. When I switched it to build in release mode that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in Visual Studio 2012, however none of the solutions worked. I am developing a 64 bit application and the solution was to choose:-

```
Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> X64
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue and option 2 below fixed it for me.

1. Remove any app.config file (not sure why, but one of the MS forums has a few of these posts with this solution) and
2. Ensure that within the configuration properties of the solution the project is set to build!!