# "Test Tools" area not showing up in VS Options

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, when I go to the "Tools" menu and select "Options..." the window does not show an area for "Test Tools."  I know it's supposed to be there because I have been seeing other posts saying I need to change a setting in there (references: [this](http://www.iamtonyzhou.com/asp-net/resolve-playback-engine-is-already-initialized-and-skipstepthreadevent/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645442/visual-studio-2010-does-not-discover-new-unit-tests)).

[image]

I'm running VS 2013 RC Ultimate.  I know 2013 is beta, but it's not showing up in my VS 2012 either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think maybe it just moved areas...there is a "Web Performance Test Tools" area that has similar options under it to what other screenshots show under the "Test Tools" section.

[image]

It would be nice if someone could verify that this is in fact the same area however.